# Test for a wolf without a tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making this 1 command, and I want to test for a wolf that does not have the tag `Tamed`. Now you might say "That's super easy just put an '!' before your tag name", But no I have this command:

```
execute @e[type=Wolf,tag=!Tamed] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[c=1,type=Wolf,tag=!Tamed] mc_Tamed 1 {Sitting:1b}
```

That is supposed to detect when a wolf is sitting but is not tamed. But for some on reason, it still executes on wolfs with the tamed tag. Now you can figure out how to fix that command OR if you know a better solution to detect a tamed wolf then that would be good also. Thanks!

Add tag commands:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=1,type=Wolf] add Tamed

/scoreboard players tag @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=2,type=Wolf] remove Tamed
```

Clock commands:

```
execute @e[type=Wolf,tag=Pet] ~ ~ ~ entitydata @e[c=1,type=Wolf,tag=Tamed] {Sitting:0b}
execute @e[type=Wolf,tag=!Tamed] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[c=1,type=Wolf] mc_Tamed 1 {Sitting:1b}
execute @e[type=Wolf,score_mc_Tamed_min=1,tag=Pet] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @e[c=1,type=Wolf,tag=Pet,tag=Pig] mc_Tamed 1 {Sitting:0b}
execute @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=3,score_mc_Tamed=3,tag=Pig] ~ ~ ~ /summon Pig ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Pig Pet",Age:-10000s,Tags:[PigPet],Invulnerable:1}
execute @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=1,tag=Pig] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=Pig,c=1] @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=2,tag=Pig]
effect @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=3] minecraft:invisibility 1 1 true
effect @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=2] minecraft:resistance 100 100 true
effect @e[tag=PigPet] minecraft:regeneration 100 100 true
/scoreboard teams join collision @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=1]
/scoreboard teams join collision @e[tag=PigPet]
/scoreboard players add @e[tag=PigPet] mc_Action 1
execute @e[score_mc_Action_min=6000,tag=PigPet] ~ ~ ~ /give @p cooked_porkchop 1
    /scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add Bacon {Item:{id:"minecraft:cooked_porkchop",Count:16b},OnGround:1b}
    execute @e[tag=Bacon] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players tag @e[r=1,score_mc_Tamed_min=1,tag=!Pet] add Pig
    execute @e[tag=Bacon] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players tag @e[r=1,score_mc_Tamed_min=1,tag=Pig,tag=!Pet] add Pet
    execute @e[tag=Pig] ~ ~ ~ kill @e[tag=Bacon,c=1,r=1]
    execute @e[tag=!Pet,type=Wolf] ~ ~ ~ particle reddust ~ ~1 ~ 0 0 0 0.001 1
    /scoreboard players set @e[tag=PigPet,score_mc_Action_min=6000] mc_Action 1
    /entitydata @e[tag=PigPet] {Age:-10000s}
    execute @e[tag=Pet] ~ ~ ~ entitydata @e[r=4,type=Item] {PickupDelay:0s}
    execute @e[tag=Pet] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=Item,r=3] @p
    execute @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=1,type=Wolf] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players tag @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=1,type=Wolf,c=1] add Tamed
    execute @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=2,type=Wolf] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players tag @e[score_mc_Tamed_min=2,type=Wolf,c=1] remove Tamed
```

Comment: Please provide the command you're using to apply the `Tamed` label.

Comment: I could be missing something, but can untamed wolves even sit normally? If the only way they can sit is through setting `Sitting:1b` with commands, then you'll probably need to also give them the Tag with that command too (I can't think of a good distinction between tamed and untamed wolves besides that).

Comment: @Skylinerw I added the taming commands. They activate right after eachother

Comment: @McMatt Is mc_Tamed ever actually being set to 2 to activate the last command, and if so when/why does this happen (wolves cannot be untamed)? Your current system will tag all wolves with `Tamed` and set their `mc_Tamed` score to 1 if they sit down. It should work to detect tamed wolves (though it can be simplified), unless you have commands that make untamed wolves sit down.

Comment: @colorfusion The tamed score is being added to when a player drops and item on the wolf. This turns them into an animal as a result.

Comment: @McMatt So a tamed wolf will be turned into non-tamed wolf, the `Tamed` tag will be removed, then if the non-tamed wolf is still sitting the `Tamed` tag will be added back to it? You might need to post all your commands in the order they are on your clock, along with what you're intending the system to do (why do you need to detect sitting non-tamed wolves, for example?)

Comment: @colorfusion I'm not detecting un-tamed wolfs I'm trying to detect when a Tamed wolf is sitting for the first time. After that the wolf gets a Tamed score of 1+, and any wolf with a 1+ score that is sitting can not have their score set back to one when they sit

Comment: "and any wolf with a 1+ score that is sitting can not have their score set back to one when they sit " - I don't understand what you mean by this part. Do you have anything commands that could cause non-tamed wolves to sit down (if so, could you paste them here)?

Comment: So to detect a newly tamed wolf I detect if a wolf is sitting (Because this is default for tamed wolfs). When I detect that they are sitting I set their tame score to 1. Then after they are NOT sitting I add 1 to their tame score. Then I need to make sure that if they sit again they will not get their tame score set back to one. At them moment I have an entity data setting any sitting wolf to stand up, but this for some reason works a tick to late (it's first command to run) and when the dog sits it's score gets set to one. So, how would I keep from any already tamed wolf from getting set to 1

Comment: *"Then after they are NOT sitting I add 1 to their tame score"* - This makes the last command remove their `Tamed` tag, which then makes the first command set their `mc_Tamed` back to 1 when they sit again, is this intentional? *"At them moment I have an entity data setting any sitting wolf to stand up, but this for some reason works a tick to late"* - Could you paste all of the commands on your clock? Kind of hard to debug order of execution mistakes without knowing most of your system. Would there be a problem with just having `/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Wolf] add Tamed {Sitting:1b}`?

Comment: @colorfusion ok does that help?

Comment: @McMatt `tag=Pig,tag=!Pet` in the 15th command isn't going to work, you can only specify one `tag=` in each selector, or it only uses the last one. Is there a reason that `Tamed` is removed in the last command? (Trying to work out what your system is doing)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do `/testfor @e[type=Wolf,tag=!Tamed]`